# Writing jquery plugin and it is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a simple jQuery plugin for my needs, using a variant of the first one in [this style guide](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/).

```
;(function($) {
    var plugin_name = 'my_plugin',
        defaults = {};

    function Plugin ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = plugin_name;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            // Plugin code - attempt to debug
            alert('hi');
        }
    }

    $.fn[plugin_name] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + plugin_name)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + plugin_name, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        })
    }

})( jQuery );
```

However, it doesn't seem to be executed when I call it. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DCRnU/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.my_plugin();
});
```

What am I missing out on?

Comment: That's not how you call a plugin, `$.fn = jQuery.prototype`, you call it on a jQuery collection.

Comment: Ah, I changed the way I called the plugin and now it's triggering, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the function properly.
If you had a `div` element in your HTML, you could call your function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").my_plugin();
});
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCRnU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because this line: `return this.each`

It's expect to get some iterable object.
But there is nothing to loop over it.

if you add something like this:

```
var array = [1];
$(array).my_plugin();
```

it'll be fine.

Comment: Wouldn't $().my_plugin(); do the same thing?